# Change private class methods

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to change the behavior of a jquery plugin without actually changing the source. For the purposes of this question, I constructed a simple example that illustrates my problem. If a have script file that attaches a class instance generator to a global variable like this:

```
(function(){

window.newMyClass = function(){
    return new myclass();
}

function myclass(){
    var privateMethod = function(){
        return "private";
    }
    this.publicMethod = function(){
        return privateMethod();
    }
}
})()
```

If I then get new instance of myclass with `var instance = window.newMyClass()`, is there any way to override the behavior of `privateMethod` on `instance`, such that `instance.publicMethod()` would call my overridden function? I was thinking I could subclass myclass, but since the myclass constructor is scoped to the immediately invoked function expression, I don't know how to do that.

Is it better just to change the plugin source? The problem with that is I'd have to host it myself instead of using a CDN, as well as re-implement the change every time an update is released.

Comment: The only thing you can do is override `publicMethod`.

Comment: There's a reason they're called "private" methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well this. Probably not, because there is no mistery with that:

```
(function(){

window.newMyClass = function(){
    return new myclass()
}

function myclass(){
    var privateMethod = function(){
        return "private";
    }
    this.publicMethod = function(){
        return privateMethod();
    }
}
})();

var instance = window.newMyClass();

instance.publicMethod = function(){
        return "new method";
}

console.log(instance.publicMethod());
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r9evbzd2/1/

Comment: Maybe explain what you did? And why?

Comment: I need to change the implementation of privateMethod, since it is called all over the class, not just in publicMethod. I included publicMethod just as an example of what I want the end behavior to be -- publicMethod returns my overridden privateMethod function.

Comment: So this is all about overriding a private (not accesible) method. I suggest the title: **Change private class methods from an instance of the class**

Comment: And what about extend the class?

Comment: Yes. Ordinarily i'd create a subclass of myclass with the overridden method, but because of the way class instances are setup I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm still confused because if you want to override `privateMethod` and what `publicMethod` does is calling `private Method`, then overriding `publicMethod` should be enough. I know you are using the code in your question as an example, but that makes it hard to try to work together in your requirement.

Comment: @noachr: Well, you can't change the implementation of `privateMethod`, it's as simple as that.